# Correct way to pass Redux store state to child components in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux

==Have edited the question as the solutions didn't work unfortunately!==

==I've now realised that it's because my Redux Store isn't updating correctly!!==

I'm trying to build a project in ReactJS with Redux that has a Redux store with state updating periodically from an Axios fetch.

This Axios fetch updates the initial store state fine.

I'm passing the store state as props to Child elements of the Parent.

When the store state changes, if a Child is affected I need the props to pass down and re-render the Child.

I had thought that if I sent the props (which are set by mapStateToProps) to a Child, and the state changed, this would re-send the prop and cause a re-render but this isn't the case.

Any advice on the correct way to acheive what I'm trying would be appreciated.

I've console logged the props from the Parent element's componentDidMount method and i'm seeing the props update as I'd expect; every time I manually change the JSON being fetched the props are altered to reflect this.

**Parent element:**

```
class Parent extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.updatePanels();
        console.log(this.props);
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.props.updatePanels();
        }, 5000);
       }

     componentWillUnmount() {
       clearInterval(this.interval)
     }

     renderList() {
        return this.props.panels.map((panel) => {
          return (
              <Child key={panel.id} lat={panel.lat} lng={panel.lng} />
          );
        });
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderList()}
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

**Child element:**

```
const Child = props => (
    <div key={props.id}>
         <div>{props.lat}</div>
         <div>{props.lng}</div>
    </div>
)
```

**Redux Action Creator**

```
import panelFetch from '../dataCalls/panelFetch';

export const updatePanels = () => {

    return async (dispatch) => {
      const response = await panelFetch.get("/panelList.json");

      console.log(response.data);

      dispatch ({
        type: 'UPDATE_PANELS',
        payload: response.data
      });
    };
  };
```

**Redux Update Panels Reducer**

```
export default (state = [], action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
      case 'UPDATE_PANELS':
        return action.payload;
      default:
        return state;
    }

  };
```

**Redux Reducers**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import updatePanelsReducer from './updatePanelsReducer'; //compartmentalise our reducer

const panelReducer = () => {
    return [{
        "id": 400016,
        "lat": 51.509865,
        "lng": -0.118092
    }, {
        "id": 400017,
        "lat": 51.509865,
        "lng": -0.118092
    }, {
        "id": 400018,
        "lat": 51.509865,
        "lng": -0.118092
    }, {
        "id": 400019,
        "lat": 51.509865,
        "lng": -0.118092
    }
];
};

export default combineReducers({
    panels: panelReducer,
    updatePanels: updatePanelsReducer
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The child component shouldn't put its props in its state.

The child component isn't updating because its render method doesn't depend on its props but on m its own internal state, which you set once in its constructor and never change.

It will work if your child component looks like this:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div key={this.props.id}>
                 <div>{this.props.lat}</div>
                <div>{this.props.lng}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

---

Also, you may want to consider getting rid of all the boilerplate of a class component, especially if you're only using its render method. You can rewrite it as a function component like this:

```
const Child = props => (
    <div key={props.id}>
         <div>{props.lat}</div>
         <div>{props.lng}</div>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: especially the part about rewriting the component.

Comment: No joy with this unfortunately. I've refactored Child to a functional component as above and the same problem occurs. Could this be something to do with my mapStateToProps?

`const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { panels: state.panels }
  };

export default connect (mapStateToProps, { updatePanels: updatePanels })(Parent);`

Weird that i'm seeing correct output from the console when logging the props though

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're setting the `Child` component's state only once initially in the constructor. The subsequent changes in the props won't update the state of the `Child` component.

You can use React's `getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)` method to set the initial state and then update the state after the props update. Read it here 
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

OR

You can just simply pass down the props to the `Child` component without having to set the state.

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div key={this.props.id}>
                 <div>{this.props.lat}</div>
                <div>{this.props.lng}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Hope this helps !